# Getting the polygon for a given airport

Tags: python, polygon

What I need to do is to get the bounding box polygon for all airports worldwide.  The only way I'm aware of do this, is by using `esy.osm.pbf`.  I've written the following code:

```
def get_airport_points(airport, file_path):
    osm = esy.osm.pbf.File(file_path)
    lat_lons = OrderedDict()
    index = 0
    print("There are " + str(len(airport.refs)) + " nodes to go through.")
    for ref in airport.refs:
        print(str(index))
        index = index + 1
        nodes = [entry for entry in osm if entry.id == ref]
        lonlat = nodes[0].lonlat
        print(lonlat)
        print(type(lonlat[1]))
        print(type(lonlat[0]))
        lat_lons[ref] = ([lonlat[1], lonlat[0]])
    return lat_lons
```

But it takes much too long to do this, that's just for a single airport, and I need to do it for all airports worldwide.  Is there a better way of fetching the latitudes and longitudes for the polygons for all airports worldwide?

Comment: are you sure you need the bounding box of **every** airport? could you manage with a point for a lot of them? in which case natural earth has an airports layer.

Comment: Yes, that would probably be OK.   Would you guide me as to how I can get that please?  https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/ - I can see Cultural, Physical and Raster here.

Comment: Airports are cultural objects and you probably want details so look at 1:10M (https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_airports.zip)

Comment: OK thanks, but that's not going to work, as it's just one point for each airport.

Comment: How are you defining "airport"? Public transportation only, or do you want military and private installations with runways? Grass strip airfields? Is there a definition of "airport" from some regulatory body that you might be using? These things change and fall out of use and new ones are created, so do you care about the time point?

Comment: Are you using a pbf file here? Where from?

Comment: You could pay Geofabrik to extract the data you want from the OSM Planet file, for a fee. https://www.geofabrik.de/data/